# show that $R^n$ and $C^n$ are not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

i need to prove it using the definition of compactness by successions "A metric space X is said to be
compact if every sequence in X has a convergent subsequence".

my attempt:

a)in the case of $R^n$:

suppose that $R^n$ is compact and take the sequence $x_k = (k+1,...,k+n)$ this sequence don't have a convergent subsequence, it's a contradiction, hence $R^n$ is not compact.

For the case of $ C ^ n $ I would try something similar but I don't know how to take a proper sequence.

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ is a subset of $\Bbb C^n$!

Comment: Do the same thing: take any nonzero vector $v$ and look at the sequence $v, 2v, 3v, \ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by Heine Borel Theorem, a set $X$ is compact iff it's closed and bounded. Now, neither $\mathbb{R}^n$ not $\mathbb{C}^n$ is bounded, so you can directly state that they are not compact.

---

However, if you want to prove using the sequential criterion, what you've written for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is true. You can take a simpler example anyway, e.g. $x_k := (k, 0, 0, \cdots , 0)$ . This sequence doesn't have any convergent subsequence. So, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact.

Now, remember that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a superset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ . So you can simply consider the same sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty ~\subset \mathbb{R}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ which certainly shows that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it has helped me a lot :)